# how to retrieve largest value from a particular column in cassandra?

Tags: php, tags, cassandra, thrift

how can i retrieve largest value from a particular column in Cassandra ? i am storing tag name as name and number of clicks as value in Cassandra. Now i need to find out what are the most popular tags(based on the click)? Please Help me

example :

1. supercolumn : movies
   columnname : "matrix"
   value      : 10(number of clicks)
2. supercolumn : movies
   columnname : "titanic"
   value      : 0(number of clicks)
3. supercolumn : movies
   columnname : "avatar"
   value      : 5(number of clicks)

now i need to get the result like matrix,avatar and titanic respectively(based on the value desc)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have another CF with movie names as row keys, and column values as cnames -- then the ordering of column names makes "get the one with largest value" trivial.